# Branch history for branch prediction inside a function on intel X86-64

Tags: x86-64, branch-prediction

Is branch history preserved across function calls or does it get re-initialized every time the function is entered.

Comment: A processor doesn't know anything about function calls.  It only knows about addresses where jump and call instructions once executed.  Nothing is being reset when you make a function call in a C program.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for the info. I associate a function call with a jump, unless its inlined. Glad to know history is maintained across jumps.

Comment: The processor does see calls, but there's no reason to reset the history everytime you enter - it would make a horrible predictor without this history. Just think of `while (!finished()) { ...`